# How do you check for undefined value before a query in .NET for parse?

Tags: .net, parse-platform

The error that I get as below. I've found out that it occur when I query a field which is "undefined".

So how do you check for a field which is undefined in Parse?

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "The given key was not present in the dictionary.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)\r\n   at Parse.ParseObject.get_Item(String key)\r\n   at Parse.ParseObject.Get[T](String key)\r\n
```

Comment: Is there a `TryGet` method you can use?

Comment: `Parse` and `ParseObject` aren't .NET Framework classes. Where are they from? Did you create them, are you using a third-party library? Does ParseObject have a TryGet method?

Comment: And how is the question related to parsing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to the `Parse.com` platform's [ParseObject](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseObject.htm) class, you can use the [ParseObject.ContainsKey](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/M_Parse_ParseObject_ContainsKey.htm) method to check if a key exists, before calling Get, eg:

```
if (someParseObject.Contains(someKey))
    myVar=someParseObject.Get(someKey);
```